# Passing value from method to method

Tags: java

Why does the value inside the salary is not being parse from Salary method to Commission method ?

```
package salesrepresentativeapp;

import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 *
 * @author Kirin
 */
public class SalesRepresentativeAPP {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String ID;
        String name;
        int yearServiced;
        double salesVolume;

        //System.out.println("Please enter your ID : ");
       // ID = sc.nextLine();
       // System.out.println("Please enter your Name : ");
       // name = sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Please enter your Year of Service : ");
        yearServiced = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Please enter your sales volume : ");
        salesVolume = sc.nextDouble();

        SalesRepresentative s1 = new SalesRepresentative("id", "name", yearServiced, salesVolume);

        //System.out.println("ID : " + s1.getID() + "\nName : " + s1.getName());
        System.out.println("Your total salary is : " + s1.Commision() + "\nBasic Salary is : " + s1.Salary());

    }

}
```

.

```
package salesrepresentativeapp;

/**
 *
 * @author Kiin
 * v1.0
 */
public class SalesRepresentative {

     private String ID;
     private String name;
     private int yearServiced,salary;
     private double salesVolume,commision;


    public SalesRepresentative(String ID, String name, int yearServiced, double salesVolume){
        this.ID = ID;
        this.name = name;
        this.yearServiced = yearServiced;
        this.salesVolume = salesVolume;
    }

    public int Salary(){
        if (yearServiced >=1 && yearServiced <= 5) {
            salary = 1200;
        }
        else if (yearServiced >=6 && yearServiced <= 10 ) {
            salary = 1800;
        }
        else if (yearServiced > 10) {
            salary = 2300;
        }
        return salary;
    }

    public double Commision(){
         if (salesVolume >= 1 && salesVolume <= 99.99) {
            commision = salary + (salary * 0.05);
        }
        else if (salesVolume >= 100.00 && salesVolume <= 299.99 ) {
            commision = salary + (salary * 0.10);
        }
        else if (salesVolume >= 300.00) {
            commision = salary + (salary * 0.15);
        }
        return commision;
    }

    public String getID(){
        return ID;
    }

    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }
}
```

When I did not put the salary in the equation the method works well. But when I put the salary inside the equation the method return value 0.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your code there is quite a few changes you should make to improve see the edited copies and I will explain

```
public class SalesRepresentative {

     private String ID;
     private String name;
     private int yearServiced,salary;
     private double salesVolume,commision;


    public SalesRepresentative(String ID, String name, int yearServiced, double salesVolume){
        this.ID = ID;
        this.name = name;
        this.yearServiced = yearServiced;
        this.salesVolume = salesVolume;

        salary();
        commision();
    }

    private void salary(){
        if (yearServiced >=1 && yearServiced <= 5) {
            salary = 1200;
        }
        else if (yearServiced >=6 && yearServiced <= 10 ) {
            salary = 1800;
        }
        else if (yearServiced > 10) {
            salary = 2300;
        }
    }

    private void commision(){
         if (salesVolume >= 1 && salesVolume <= 99.99) {
            commision = salary + (salary * 0.05);
        }
        else if (salesVolume >= 100.00 && salesVolume <= 299.99 ) {
            commision = salary + (salary * 0.10);
        }
        else if (salesVolume >= 300.00) {
            commision = salary + (salary * 0.15);
        }
    }

    public double getCommision()
    {
        return commision;
    }

    public int getSalary()
    {
        return salary;
    }

    public String getID(){
        return ID;
    }

    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }
}
```

Your method names should by convention be camel case. I have changed their scope from `public` to `private` (meaning the can only be called within this class) and called them in the constructor. The order in which you call these methods are VERY important as commission can not be calculated before salary has been calculated.

Also I have changed their return types to `void` due to the methods being updating values within the class. I have created two getter methods `getSalary()` & `getCommission()` - these will be called by your application to return the values. See the implementation below:

```
public class SalesRepresentativeAPP {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String ID;
        String name;
        int yearServiced;
        double salesVolume;

        System.out.println("Please enter your Year of Service : ");
        yearServiced = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Please enter your sales volume : ");
        salesVolume = sc.nextDouble();

        SalesRepresentative s1 = new SalesRepresentative("id", "name", yearServiced, salesVolume);

        System.out.println("Your total salary is : " + s1.getCommision() + "\nBasic Salary is : " + s1.getSalary());

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You call the Commision method first, the value is edited after you call Salaray.
Change your System.out to this instead.

```
 System.out.println("Basic Salary is : " + s1.Salary() + "\nYour total salary is : " + s1.Commision());
```

Other than that method names should start with a lowercase character.

Edit: I hope that I have understood your question correctly.